# Has Apple fixed the CoreData + iCloud sync issues?

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I'm thinking about upgrading my App with iCloud sync across devices.

I'm currently using CoreData to save data, which is the best way for me. I recently read about many developers having issues with iCloud sync regarding CoreData.

So my question is: Has Apple fixed the current issues with iCloud sync for Core Data across multiple devices or should I avoid using it at this time until a future iOS update?